# Remotely Accessing Linux Mint(GUI) using Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, vnc, remote-access, mint

## The problem:

My primary laptop is running ubuntu and I recently fixed up an older machine which my parents used to use. I upgraded some necessary hardware with plans to make it into a NAS server using FreeNAS, now TrueNAS, but they've removed the support for booting it using a flash drive so I ended up going with mint which is lightweight and I have experience using it, the problem I'm facing is that since that laptop's keyboard is disconnected and I don't have any space for it near my setup, I want to use it remotely, it's nearby but since I've set my keyboard and everything up I don't want to unplug everything from the KVM, remove all the cable ties to use the keyboard, I'm relatively new to Linux and have been using Windows. I already looked up some solutions but most of them I found are to make it into a server and nothing about connecting with ubuntu
[Mint Forum about accessing using a VNC server](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=369092) and another one linked in the same forum [Another form about another VNC server](https://tecadmin.net/setup-x11vnc-server-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/#google_vignette),

### What I'm going to be using it for

Mainly to learn more things and explore, I'm not keen to doing that as much in my main laptop which I'm also using for work and some dumb mistakes I might make might cost me my job, I want to use the GUI not just the terminal, any links or help will be appreciated, thanks

This laptop stays in my room but I'd like a solution where I can use it without having to remove everything from my setup and plugging it into the other laptop, my KVM is a 2 device one and I'm using my laptop and a Mac mini with it so that's not an option either. Any solutions or guidance would be appreciated, Thanks